# How to send an integer through pyserial with Python to an Arduino and get back the same result?

Tags: serial, programming, python

There has been similar questions all over the internet but none of them seem to answer my question, so can anybody tell me what is wrong with this code and how I can fix it?

Python code:

```
import serial

arduino_linux=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0",9600)
while True:
    print('write:',str.encode('90')) #print the sent value through the serial to check it with the readed value
    arduino_linux.write(str.encode('90'))#send the following value
    print('readed:',arduino_linux.read())#read the same value back from the arduino
```

my arduino code is as follows

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  Serial.write(Serial.read());

}
```

this is a simple sample of a project, my aim from this code is to send the integer number 90 from the pyserial and make sure the value the Arduino is reading is the same integer.

In case if necessary my project is an object follower with object detector and after calculating all the angles and everything it sends them to the Arduino so the Arduino can act up on the servo's.

This is the result I am getting:

[image]

But I would like something like:

```
write:b '90'
```

`readed:b '90'`, not `b'9'` or `b'0'`

I would also like to know how I can change these bytes to integers before I write them to a servo.

Comment: what version of python and the pySerial library you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Serial.write()` on Arduino to send raw bytes. `print` converts them to text.

`read` is not blocking, it doesn't wait for a byte and returns -1 if the receive buffer is empty. Check if read returned -1 or use `Serial.available()` to get the number of bytes in the RX buffer.

Serial 'echo':

```
void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    Serial.write(Serial.read());
  }
}
```

Comment: i have seen it and used Serial.write().  but i dont seem to quit understand what you said for the second problem. give me some specific example. Thanks